# Bootstrap Grid for Django website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for improve my Django website and especially the CSS part. I don't have knowledge about CSS because I'm beginning to learn this library.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I would like to get your opinions about columns using and the cutting of my Django website.

It's the first time I'm using `.col-md-x` and I don't know if it's true? My website application will be use with a large screen but also tablet or smartphone.

I have two examples :

**Global website page**
[image]

**Variant** 
[image]

Can I write my script in order to get this kind of things? Is it correct to write CSS/Bootstrap3 like this?

Thank you
**EDIT :**

My script for base template looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        {% load staticfiles %}
        {% load static %}
        {% load user_tags %}

        <title> DatasystemsEC - Page non trouvée </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Not_Found.css"/>

    </head>

    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.datasystems.fr/"> DatasystemsEC </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Home tab -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li> 
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class = "dropdown">
                                <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">
                                            </span> Informations Mairie
                                <b class = "caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href = "{% url "Mairieform" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Créer/Editer les informations de la Mairie </a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "{% url "Mairieresume" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Consulter les informations de la Mairie </a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Resume Tab with acts -->

                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                                            </span>  Actes Etat Civil <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                                            </span> Fiches Individuelles 
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "home" %}">Accueil Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "form" %}">Création Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "searched" %}">Consultation Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                                            <li><a href="{% url "edited" %}">Edition Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "deleted" %}">Suppression Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BChome" %}">Accueil Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCform" %}">Création Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/">Consultation Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Actes de Reconnaissance / Adoption </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Accueil Actes de Reconnaissance</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Création Actes de Reconnaissance</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Consultation Actes de Reconnaissance</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Actes de Mariage</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Accueil Actes de Mariage</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Création Actes de Mariage</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Consultation Actes de Mariage</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Actes de Divorce</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Accueil Actes de Divorce</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Création Actes de Divorce</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Consultation Actes de Divorce</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Actes de Décès</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Accueil Actes de Décès</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Création Actes de Décès</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Consultation Actes de Décès</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>


                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book">
                                            </span> Tables Annuelles & Décennales <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                                            </span> Edition Tables annuelles
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "annuel" %}">Naissances</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Reconnaissances</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Mariages</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Décès</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Edition Tables décennales</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Naissances</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Reconnaissances</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Mariages</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Décès</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class = "dropdown">
                                <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">
                                            </span> Recensement
                                <b class = "caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href = "{% url "Rhome" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Liste Recensement </a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "{% url "Rform" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Edition de l'Attestation de Recensement </a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                            <li><a href="{% url "logout" %}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Déconnexion </a></li>
                                            <li><a>{{user.username}} </a></li>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <li><a href="{% url "login" %}" style = "padding-left: 600px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion </align></a></li>
                                        {% endif %}


                                        {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                                            <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/admin.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                        {% elif request.user|has_group:"visiteur"%}
                                            <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/visiteur.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                        {% elif request.user|has_group:"employé"%}
                                            <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/employé.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                        {% elif request.user|has_group:"officier"%}
                                            <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/officier.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                        {% elif request.user|has_group:"maire"%}
                                            <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/maire.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                        {% endif %}

                            </ul>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        event.stopPropagation(); 
                        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>   

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="title">
                            {% block title %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar1">

                        <div class="left-navigation">

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> Accueil</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Informations Mairie</strong></h5>
                                {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                                <li><a href="{% url "Mairieform" %}">Créer/Editer les informations</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                <li><a href="{% url "Mairieresume" %}">Consulter les informations</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes Etat Civil</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "home" %}">Fiches Identités</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BChome" %}">Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Actes de Reconnaissance / Adoption</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Actes de Mariage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Actes de Divorce</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Actes de Décès</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Tables Annuelles & Décennales</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "annuel" %}">Tables Annuelles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Tables Décennales</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span>Recensement</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "Rhome" %}">Liste de Recensement</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "Rform" %}">Attestation de Recensement</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> DatasystemsDOC</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="https://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?folderId=8552450">Individus</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?folderId=8978465">Tables</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?folderId=8978476">Recensement</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Configuration</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "options" %}">Thème</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            {% endif %}

                            <ul class="list">
                                <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Aide & Support</strong></h5>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Besoin d'aide ?</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Mentions légales</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <body> 
                    <div class="col-md-10">

                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock content %}  

                    </div>
                    </body>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <footer>
                            <p class="text-muted footer"> &copy; DatasystemsEC 2017 - Tous droits réservés <br /> Version Démo</p>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

</html>
```

I added some classes `row` and `.col-md-x`. I want to structure my script correctly with Bootstrap grid but I never made this before.

Comment: "I would like to get your opinions" — Questions asking for opinions are off-topic.

Comment: "It's the first time I'm using .col-md-x and I don't know if it's true?" — This sentence doesn't make sense. What don't you know is true? Surely you know if it is the first time you're using that feature of Bootstrap or not?

Comment: "Can I write my script in order to get this kind of things?" — What what script? To get what? The point of Bootstrap Grids is that it has classes already set up for different sized displays.

Comment: As I said, I never used Bootstrap correctly. Pictures that I've made is what my Django website has to looking for. I will edit my question with my script and Bootstrap `row` and `col`. But I don't know if I can write things like this or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for you--

**no.1**

you are saying that your website will be viewed in all screen sizes so you have to make it responsive.
In order to make a site responsive in bootstrap you need to use all the `responsive grid classes`---`col-sm-* col-xs-* col-md-* col-lg-*`. Your design will not look proper in xs and sm devices.

**no.2**

You don't need to use `col-md-*` in the nav as it automatically takes full width.

**no.3**

in the variant portion You are using a blank `.col-md-1` that's not how you achieve blank spacing in bootstrap rather use `offset` classes. Use `.col-md-1 col-md-offset-1` it will create a blank column.

**no.4**

Your design won't look good in extra small devices. Try to introduce more rows for xs devices in order to stack your contents in the middle portion(although this is subjective as I don't know what contents you are going to have..just a general idea from my side.)

Comment: They downvoted it because your question was opinion based and I answered it! anyways it helped you..great

Comment: Anyway I take account suggestions.